# Setting Port 443 ssl; loads different server directory?

Tags: https, nginx

Running Nginx + Centos 7.2 + Wordpress

I am installing SSL for a domain of mine, and when I set the port in my serer configuration to `listen 443 ssl;`when I visit the domain, it prompts me with the "Welcome to nginx"

[image]

But if I change it back to `listen 80;` it will display my website.

Here is my server domain configuration:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
    root   /var/www/data/domain.com/public_html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/www/data/domain.com/public_html/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And this here is my nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

}
```

I've spent the last 4 days trying to get SSL to work, and well, I haven't been so lucky.

Also, when I add `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` to my domain config, I just get the "too many redirects" error.

**EDIT:**

So, as you can see in my nginx.conf at the bottom, it includes `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*` So for some reason its reading my domain config, and skipping that and processing default.conf from '/etc/nginx/conf.d/*' instead.

Well, still thinking what else I can do differently.

Comment: What Distro are you using? Why are you mixing sites-enabled and conf.d?  it's a little bit unusual. Where is resides the config for domain.com? What in the default.conf ?

Comment: You have to use `https` protocol, otherwise browser still goes to port 80 with plain `http` and your server block doesn't listen to it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Well, Alexey Ten gave the answer in his comment: If you call your website without explicitly using https ("https://www.domain.com") your server is being addressed by port 80, and without redirect your server listening on 443 won't serve anything.

Where did you put the redirect directive? You have to write it into another server block, like so:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

This redirects everything to https. 
You can add a server name directive ("server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;" to that block, if you only want requests for domain.com to be redirected to https.